# how to make a several copies of a website on the same server for different client - django

Tags: django, postgresql, multi-tenant

i have a customer , he has two hotels , and he wants set both hotels on the same server , but each of them has different data , i tried to use [django-tenant-schemas](https://django-tenant-schemas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html) here is my settings.py

```
SHARED_APPS = [
    'tenant_schemas',
    'users',
    'rosetta',
    'widget_tweaks',
    'import_export',

    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

TENANT_APPS = [
    'rooms',
    'vistors',
    'booking',
    'costs',
    'payments',
    'cancel',
]

INSTALLED_APPS = list(SHARED_APPS) + [app for app in TENANT_APPS if app not in SHARED_APPS]
TENANT_MODEL= "rooms.Hotel"

#db engine 
'ENGINE': 'tenant_schemas.postgresql_backend',
```

my models.py

```
class Hotel(TenantMixin):
    hotel_name = models.CharField(max_length=40,unique=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.hotel_name

class Room(models.Model):
    room_no = models.IntegerField()
    #others
```

and i have more models but all of them inherited from `models.Model` ,in the `public` schema it only created tables for `SHARED_APP` apps , `TENANT_APP` not created

and i try `manage.py migrate_schemas` it raise this error

> if public_schema_name in tenants: TypeError: argument of type 'TenantQueryset' is not iterable

is there another way to achieve it please ? i need something like this : home page shows two hotels name : `Hotel A` and `Hotel B` when i click on `Hotel A` shows all data which owns by Hotel A and both has same menu but they are different in contents for example booking in Hotel B should bring me to all booking in hotel B and the same for hotel A?! is the possible ? or should i create separate models for both !?
thank you

Comment: I don't know much about Django but why opt for separate schemas when you can simply achieve this by having a `discriminator-column such as hotel_id` in every table and reference the rows for whichever hotel you require based on appropriate `where clause`.

Comment: @AdilKhalil yes i did it as well , but it wont success in the urls for menu

Answer (score 1):

You may have two different databases and route your requests to the particular database depends on selected hotel.

The selection you may keep in Cookies.

I.e.:

**settings.py**

```
DATABASES = {
    'hotel_a': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'hotel_a_db',
        # etc
    },
    'hotel_b': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'hotel_b_db',
        # etc
    }
}
```

then in your business logic you refer to the selected hotel via `using()` as a given database for querysets:

**views.py**

```
def hotel_view(request):
    hotel = request.COOKIES.get('hotel', 'hotel_a')  # a - for default
    rooms = models.Room.objects.using(hotel).all()
    # etc
```

For more information you can refer to the documentation of multiple databases:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/multi-db/

Another solution could be to use on each model additional `ForeignKey` for hotel:

```
class Room(models.Model):
    hotel = models.ForeignKey(Hotel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

However, you will then need to define it on each model and in case there are unique fields - they have to be replaced to be unique in combination with hotel. E.g.:

```
class Room(models.Model):
    room_no = models.IntegerField(unique=False)  #but has to be unique per hotel
    hotel = models.ForeignKey(Hotel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('hotel', 'room_no')
```

Comment: thank you , i tried FK before , but it needs to have the same urls with different parameters , you know its too complicated in django

Comment: and if you have two different database , the superuser should create two different account

Comment: @HunarMohammed, I think for your case having a different databases makes sense. However, it will be less convenient if you have a lot of hotels.

Regarding superuser I am not sure - I think one is enough, but better to check with documentation. I think when you start trying it will be more clear

Comment: thank you so much , ill try it and let you know the result